# Cannot remove class in div from within, JS

Tags: javascript, html

As you can see I would like to remove `extended` class from a parent div. For some reason that does not work. How can I make it to work?

```js
function closeExpandedProject() {
  const expandedElement = document.querySelector('.expanded');
  expandedElement.classList.remove('expanded');
}
```

```css
.expanded { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<div class="project-item-wrapper expanded">
  Here is some text
  <span class="close" onclick="closeExpandedProject()">X</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess its not selecting the node properly. you can try something like this:
const expandedElement = this.parentNode;
expandedElement.classList.remove('expanded');

Comment: It's working for me if I paste your code into a StackOverflow snippet. Any errors in your console?

Comment: As the onclick event is on the div u want to close itself, why not just toggle the expanded class in the parent of the click target ?

Comment: I made a snippet. Please add relevant CSS - my CSS was just for demonstration and it seems to work as intended

Comment: it is working on first time. If you click again than it gives error because the element is not found with that class. that is already removed.

Answer (score 2):

I believe The problem is you are selecting through querySelector is not the parent of the element you clicked. You have to select the parentNode of the clicked element.

This may solve your problem:

```
<div class="project-item-wrapper expanded">
  <span class="close" onclick="closeExpandedProject(this)">X</span>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function closeExpandedProject(element) {
    const expandedElement = element.parentNode;
    expandedElement.classList.remove('expanded');
  }
```

Comment: @mplungjan But still the OP code doesn't ensure that the same element is selected that is been clicked. I believe this solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use a target selector to add the event listener to the object instead of writing onclick=foo()

You can do it using Id or the ClassName.

With ClassName, it selected a list of objects so you have to access the 0th index

```
document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0].addEventListener("click", closeExpandedProject);
```

Works directly with Id

```
document.getElementById("close").addEventListener("click", closeExpandedProject);
```

```js
function closeExpandedProject() {
  console.log("in function")
  const expandedElement = document.querySelector('.expanded');
  expandedElement.classList.remove('expanded');
}

document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0].addEventListener("click", closeExpandedProject);
```

```css
.expanded { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<div class="project-item-wrapper expanded">
  Here is some text
  <span class="close" id="close">X</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So yes, it works, but the problem comes from a different source. I had also second listener which were adding this class. So after using `stopImmediatePropagation` everything works just fine. Sorry for confusion if any.